# How to integrate a News-feed indicator for an MT4 StrategyTester backtesting?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, technical-indicator

I need a news indicator that shows me news starts from 2016, and the impact(big, medium, small), the outcome (positive, negative news). Are they such indicators available?

I am aware of FFCal and FFC (https://www.mql5.com/en/code/15931), but seems that they only provide a limited period of times?

Answer (score 3):

For backtesting you may need a specific thread on ForexFactory where its author updates the news events from 2007 with their impact, datetime, name and currencies. then you will need to write a tool that reads such csv file and acts if necessary. i havent seen it written

Comment: Thanks! Are such historical news events available on the ForexFactory and if yes on what urls? Other than that, any good sources of news feed available for back testing (of course it needs to contain years of historical news)

Comment: You will definetely find it, i think there's only one such thread but i do not remember the author. csv files are updated once a month as far as i remember, all times are in NY. and i do not know any other resources for past forex news

Comment: https://www.forexfactory.com/hanover - I believe this guy is the one who updates the news log. ask him or look for the topics he contributes.

Answer (score 1):

### These are two VERY distinct things:
(a) Fundamental Data  <sup>( a source per-se )</sup> 
(b) BackTesting integration into MT4

ForexFactory provides tabular access to (a), with some depth of the history, altogether with somewhat human-oriented navigation in html-tables for web browsing.

This does **NOT** mean, the same is machine-ready for integration into MetaTrader 4 Terminal tools, alike the Strategy Tester. Even the FFCal ( AFAIK ) is just a text-presentation of a copy of ForexFactory actual day textual values, not integrated into the Expert Advisor logic and does **NOT** provide means for "accelerated" run under Strategy Tester simulated flow of time.

This said, the solution requirement (b) dictates the approach to (a), right due to the fact, that successful Strategy Tester integration wins the both (a) and (b).

---

### A working solution: MT4 with a proxy FundamentalNewsPROCESSOR

> Example output from external FundamentalNewsPROCESSOR:
>
> ```
>     ...
>     2016-12-27  4:30am high    GBP Current Account                                                     Good?Bad for GBP
>     2016-11-03  5:00am high    GBP EU Membership Court Ruling                                          Good?Bad for GBP
>     2016-06-23 All Day high    GBP EU Membership Vote                              Leave               Good?Bad for GBP
>     2010-03-30  3:30am high    GBP Final GDP q/q                            better 0.4%      0.3%      Good?Bad for GBP 0.3%
>     2010-07-12  3:30am high    GBP Final GDP q/q                                   0.3%      0.3%      Good?Bad for GBP 0.3%
>     2016-06-30  3:30am high    GBP Final GDP q/q                                   0.4%      0.4%      Good?Bad for GBP 0.4%
>     2007-02-09  4:30am high    GBP Goods Trade Balance                             -7.1B     -7.0B     Good?Bad for GBP -6.9B     better -7.2B
>     2007-03-13  4:30am high    GBP Goods Trade Balance                      better -6.2B     -7.0B     Good?Bad for GBP -7.0B            -7.1B
>     2007-04-12  3:30am high    GBP Goods Trade Balance                      worse  -6.8B     -6.4B     Good?Bad for GBP -6.4B     worse  -6.2B
>    ...
>
>             (-------------------------|--------|----------|------|-------|--------|-------|-------|-------|-------------|---------------)
>             (aTitleNAME               | EVENTid| TIME     | CCY  | IMPACT| OPINION| ACTUAL| FCAST | PREV, | PREV_OPINION| PREV_REV_FROM )
>             (-------------------------|--------|----------|------|-------|--------|-------|-------|-------|-------------|---------------)
>             ('Prelim GDP q/q',          '61643', '7:30am',  'USD', 'high', '',      '1.1%', '1.1%', '1.2%', '',           ''            )
>             ('Fed Chair Yellen Speaks', '64178', '9:00am',  'USD', 'high', '',      '',     '',     '',     '',           ''            )
>             ('Jackson Hole Symposium',  '63417', 'All Day', 'ALL', 'high', '',      '',     '',     '',     '',           ''            )
> ```

---

works both in real-time & accelerated real-time, under StrategyTester simulation and all items are fully code-usable.

Answer (score 0):

Hanover (in forexfactory) has it, but is no longer updates it. It is from 2007 to 02June2017. This is the link: https://www.forexfactory.com/attachment.php/2339122?attachmentid=2339122&d=1496558933